# Quantificators vs pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a cartesian category with subobject classifier $\Omega$ and generic subobject $\tau:I\to\Omega$.
Consider the following pullback square:

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P @>{\bar f}>> C\\
@V{\bar g}VV @V{g}VV \\
A @>{f}>> B
\end{CD}$

I proved that for any $p:A\to\Omega$ the statement $\exists_{\bar f}(p\circ\bar g)\implies \exists_f(p)\circ g$ is true.

> What about the converse: $\exists_f(p)\circ g\implies\exists_{\bar f}(p\circ\bar g)$?

My attempts to prove it in such a category fails. On the other hand, it seems to be intuitively true in a topos.

> What assumptions are necessary in order to make it true?

Note that a similar question arises for the universal quantificator.
In particular, $\forall_f(p)\circ g\implies\forall_{\bar f}(p\circ\bar g)$ is true.
On the other hand, I found a proof for the converse $\forall_{\bar f}(p\circ\bar g)\implies \forall_f(p)\circ g$ when $g$ is monic.

Comment: Is $\bar{g} p$ supposed to be $p \circ \bar{g}$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence $\exists_{\bar f}(p\circ\bar g)\iff \exists_f(p)\circ g$ means that the pullback preserve images. Thus that equivalence holds if and only if the categor is regular.